# spring boot servlet context vs application context

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I Come from years with **Spring MVC**, I'm trying to understand some key differences with Spring boot.

With Spring MVC I used to make a very clear distinction between **application context** and **servlet context(s)**.

With Spring boot it looks like the servlet context has been pretty much deprecated and all the **beans created by means of autoconfig mechanism** live in the app context.

you can still create your servlet context of course, you have just to keep in mind the autoconfig is using application context.

so for example one implication of this is that `@RestController`s and `@Controller`s live in the application context and the Spring Boot autoconfig servlet dispatchers will use any `@RestController` or `@Controller` annotated beans in the app context.

Can you help me confirm on this or make me understand what I'm missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

In spring-springMVC system, there are two containers as your mentioned. For springboot-springMVC, debug in your controller and service with implementing ApplicationContextAware

[image: context in service]

[image: context in controller]

they use the same global applicationContext

```
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.contextAnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext
```

Comment: thanks for testing it i also did it, I'm more looking for sort of explicit documentation/explaination and best practice reccomendations.

Comment: please share :)